# dagger 2 use named annotation in provide method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I use dagger 2 library in my project. I would like to use @Named annotation to have two different types of REST adapters.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("adapter1")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
RestAdapter provideRestAdapter1() {
  return ....;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("adapter2")
RestAdapter provideRestAdapter2() {
  return ....;
}
```

Is it possible to use @Named annotation inside provide methods to dagger injects appropriate REST adapter by himself?

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Service1 provideService1(@Named("adapter1") RestAdapter restAdapter) {
  return ....;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Service2 provideService2(@Named("adapter2") RestAdapter restAdapter) {
  return ....;
}
```

Comment: can you call `provideRestAdapter1()` within `provideService1()`

Answer (score 0):

If your modules include all four methods you have above, it should work: `Service1` would use the `RestAdapter` returned by `provideRestAdapter1()`.

Or are you asking whether you can skip the first two methods, and have Dagger somehow know how to provide `@Named("adapter1") RestAdapter` itself? That isn't possible.